# Android Multiple android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So The idea is I have Two separate Activities Upper And Lower. Upper contains two buttons, plus and minus. The buttons either add 1 or minus 1, while the button activity outputs the number. So My question is how Do I get this to work using my Communiticator.java and how do I get it to work if I do not use Communiticator and I just use FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction to attach the into the container frame.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void sendData(String data) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Lower low = (Lower) ;

    low.updateDisplay(data);
    // Add Fragments by code...  Get Fragment Manager
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    // New Fragment Transaction...
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    // Create a new instance of our Fragment class (if not already done as a global variable)
    MainActivity myFragment = new MainActivity();

    // Attach the fragment instance to a frame (viewgroup) in our layout.
    // Use .replace to ensure that any previous fragment in the frame is detached.
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.lower, myFragment);

    // Commit when done (you can do multiple transactions in a single commit)
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Upper.java

```
public class Upper extends Fragment {
private Button btnPlus;
private Button btnMinus;
private int counter = 0;

Communicator com;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upper, container,false);
    btnMinus = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnPlus = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            if (com != null) com.sendData("Counter: " + counter); //Call the method in the activity class
        }
    });

    btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            if (com != null) com.sendData("Counter: " + counter); //Call the method in the activity class
        }
    });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        com = (Communicator) activity; //Reference to Main Activity
    } catch (ClassCastException castException) {
        Log.e("FragmentOne", "MainActivity didn't implement the Communicator interface");
    }
}
  }
```

Lower.java

```
 public class Lower extends Fragment {
TextView applyCount;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lower, container,false);
    applyCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    return v;
}
public void updateDisplay(String data){
    applyCount.setText(data);
}
 }
```

Comment: I think MultiActivity display is a system feature and ours is always fullscreen, maybe you can try removing ActionBar and windowBackground from Activities and display each pieace in half activity and start both, maybe it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is tat where it says you are instantiating the fragments, you are actually instantiating an Activity (MainActivity).

Activities are not to be manyally instantiated. You probably want to instantiate the Upper and Lower Fragments there.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found how do you initialize your fragments. For example you can add them right into your activity_main.xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/upperFr"
    android:name="com.test.UpperFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/loweFr"
    android:name="com.test.LowerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To retrieve your fragment from activity use findFragmentById() method on your FragmentManager (getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager() if you are using the support library). So your sendData() method in MainActivity will look like following:

```
  public void sendData(String data) {
      LowerFragment lower = (LowerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.loweFr);
      lower.updateDisplay(data);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try and just another question if I wasnt using public void sendData(String data) and was just using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction on my mainactivity how would i go about that